# How to achieve a modal similar to Bootstrap modal in .NET MAUI?

Tags: modal-dialog, .net-maui

How can I achieve a Bootstrap modal dialog on .NET MAUI? Where..

- Backdrop fade in or out
- Modal content slide up or down
- Modal can be close by clicking backdrop or by clicking custom close button

I've tried to find some existing libraries but have not been able to get the same effect.

Desired modal link: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/11412401?key=4805d42e3e44dbabb15ff52cc2d70369

Comment: Can you show us something visually may be so we have a better understanding of what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @FreakyAli, sure. I edit the original post and add a link on my desired modal effect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the BottomSheet control for this,

More information here: https://blogs.xgenoapps.com/post/2022/07/23/maui-bottom-sheet

Add the namespace:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XGENO.Maui.Controls;assembly=Maui.Controls.BottomSheet"
```

And then all you have to do is something like:

```
<controls:BottomSheet
x:Name="simpleBottomSheet"
HeaderText="Simple Example">

    <controls:BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent> 
        <Label
            Text="Hello from Bottom Sheet. This is a simple implementation with no customization." />
    </controls:BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent>
    
</controls:BottomSheet>
```

Also, the GitHub is here : https://github.com/naweed/Maui.Controls.BottomSheet

Also, I have a free set of controls (Android/iOS) you can check out if you are interested. It already has a bunch of controls and I am planning to add more: https://github.com/FreakyAli/MAUI.FreakyControls

Answer (score 0):

You could use net maui toolkit to open a popup page and show as modal.
Refer to this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM7opXlu-MU